# jest: document is not defined & puppeteer

Tags: jestjs

I have setup test environment for puppeteer, as described in doc, but suddenly got the error with usual test with `react-test-renderer`

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
}
```

As I've read suggestions for the error - `testEnvironment` should be set to `jsdom` but it's set to `NodeEnvironment` ansector class.
(https://jestjs.io/docs/ro/puppeteer)

How to have both types of tests worked?

Comment: use jest's `--env=jsdom`